# Having trouble centering a div with social icons

Tags: html, css

I have a selection of social media icons which I wish to position at the bottom of my website centrally, inside a box div.

My code looks right to me but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="footerBar">
    <div id="icons">
        <a href="https://youtube.com/MYPROFILE"><img class="socialicon" <img         src="images/icons/youtube_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/youtube_red.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/youtube_dark.png'" alt="Subscribe on YouTube" width="32" height="32">

        <a href="https://twitter.com/MYPROFILE"><img class="socialicon" <img src="images/icons/twitter_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/twitter_blue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/twitter_dark.png'" alt="Follow on Twitter" width="32" height="32">

        <a href="https://instagram.com/MYPROFILE"><img class="socialicon" <img src="images/icons/instagram_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/instagram_beige.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/instagram_dark.png'" alt="Follow on Instagram" width="32" height="32">

        <a href="https://behance.com/MYPROFILE"><img class="socialicon" <img src="images/icons/behance_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/behance_blue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/behance_dark.png'" alt="Follow on Behance" width="32" height="32">

        <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/MYPROFILE/"><img class="socialicon" <img src="images/icons/linkedin_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/linkedin_blue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/linkedin_dark.png'" alt="Connect on LinkedIn" width="32" height="32">

        <a href="https://vimeo.com/MYPROFILE"><img class="socialicon" <img src="images/icons/vimeo_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/vimeo_blue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/vimeo_dark.png'" alt="Subscribe on Vimeo" width="32" height="32">

    <a href="https://dribbble.com/MYPROFILE"><img class="socialicon" <img                      src="images/icons/dribbble_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_pink.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_dark.png'" alt="Follow on Dribbble" width="32"     height="32">
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#footerBar
{
padding:5px;
width:75%;
height:50px;
margin:10px auto;
border:1px solid #1e1e1e;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.socialicon 
{
float:left;
width:32px;
height:32px;
margin:auto;
}

.socialicon a
{
float:left;
width:32px;
height:32px;
margin:auto;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: your html-code posted at least looks totally wrong. plz take a look at it and create a fiddle for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7U4aE/4/

By adding `#icons { text-align: center; }` and `a { display: inline-block; }`, it aligns all of the child elements to the center of the div. You can then add spacing between each icon if necessary.

Also, I fixed the `<img>` tags, as your implementation was a bit broken/messy. You don't need to nest the `<img <img ...>` as you did, just have one like this:

`<img class="socialicon" src="..." onmouseover="..." onmouseout="..." alt="Subscribe on YouTube" width="32" height="32" />`

You also didn't close your `<a>` tags, which I added.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with this, extremely grateful for the polite help from not just yourself but everyone above as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing `float: left;` from `.socialicon` .

Also, fix the image tags

```
<img class="socialicon" <img src=
```

to

```
<img class="socialicon" src= ...
```

and end the tag

```
<img class="..." src="..." />
```

Brynn

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `float: left` from `.socialicon` and use `text-align: center` to `#footerbar`